# Passing dependency in browserify, soma.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, browserify, browserify-shim

For those who haven't worked with `soma.js`, it is a micro-framework, which comes with 2 core files - `soma.js` and `soma-template.js`. They are both on `npm`, so in my project, instead of hard coding the cdn urls in my `html` page, I use `var soma = require('soma.js');` and `soma.template = require('soma-template');`

However, this wasn't working. So I started digging in and found that `soma-template npm module source code` looks something like this:

```
(function(soma){
   // code here
}(this['soma'] = this['soma'] || {}));
```

If I change `this` to `window`, then it all works. However, in the ideal world, I don't want to be poking around the npm module source code and I would rather configure it within my `app.js` main entry point somehow.

It almost feels like I need to pass the current scope of `soma` variable to it, but I'm not sure how to do it..

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What does your current browserify/browserify-shim config look like?

Answer (score 0):

So I went through all the source code and finally managed to fix this. In case someone has the same issue, I fixed it by doing the following:

```
var soma     = require('soma.js'),
    template = require('soma-template');

soma.plugins.add(template.Plugin);
```